# How can I build a transaction with a dynamic list of mutators or operations using the Go SDK?

Tags: transactions, operations, go-sdk

I'm trying to submit many operations in a single transaction that are built up dynamically. How can I convert these operations to a Stellar Transaction?

Please provide code samples if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the spread operator on an object of type `[]build.TransactionMutator` that is passed into the `build.Transaction` method (on `github.com/stellar/go/build`).

Here's a code sample:

```
import (
    “github.com/stellar/go/build"
)

// BuildWithOps builds a transaction with a dynamic list of operations
func BuildWithOps(sourceAccount string, seq uint64, network build.Network, ops []build.TransactionMutator) (*build.TransactionBuilder, error) {
    // build an array of mutators initialized with the essential values
    muts := []build.TransactionMutator{
        build.Sequence{Sequence: seq},
        network,
        build.SourceAccount{AddressOrSeed: sourceAccount},
    }

    // dynamically add more mutators/operations as needed
    muts = append(muts, ops...)

    // build the transaction from these mutators and check for an error
    tx, err := build.Transaction(muts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return tx, nil
}
```

Comment: One note, `tx.Err` not longer exists. `build.Transaction` returns `tx` and `err`.