# (Dup for different SDK) How can I build a transaction with a dynamic list of mutators or operations using the JS SDK?

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, operations

This is exactly what I am after but in JS. 
[How can I build a transaction with a dynamic list of mutators or operations using the Go SDK?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/379/how-can-i-build-a-transaction-with-a-dynamic-list-of-mutators-or-operations-usin)

Something like this would be great, and then it'd be easy to loop over  and abstract out from an array of operations. Likewise simply setting new Transaction.operations = an array of operations would be great.

```
    var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
    transaction.addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: pubKey,
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        amount: "1"
    }));

    transaction.addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
            destination: pubKey3,
            asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
            amount: "1"
        }))
    transaction.build();
    transaction.sign(StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(privKey2));
```

Comment: you can use an approach simillar to this https://github.com/dolcalmi/space-center/blob/master/lib/transaction-helper.js and use it like this https://github.com/dolcalmi/space-center/blob/master/lib/resources/assets.js#L30

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, it should look like this:

```
const horizon = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/')
/**
* @param sourceAccountSecret {String} - account secret key
* @param operations {Array<StellarSdk.Operation>} - operations to apply
* @returns {Promise<StellarSdk.Transaction>}
**/
function submitOperations(sourceAccountSecret, operations) {
    if (operations.length > 100) return Promise.reject(new Error('A transaction may contain up to 100 operations. Use batching to send send more than 100 operations a time.'))
    //retrieve keypair from secret key
    let keypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(sourceAccountSecret)
    //load account sequence from Horizon server
    return server.loadAccount(keypair.publicKey())
        .then(account => {
            //build and sing the transaction
            const txBuilder = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
            txBuilder.operations = operations
            const tx = txBuilder.build()
            tx.sign(keypair)
            //submit the transaction to Stellar network
            return server.submitTransaction(tx)
        })
}
```

And then call the function from your code:

```
submitOperations('SA45...8DA1', [
    StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: pubKey,
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        amount: "1"
    }),
    StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: pubKey3,
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        amount: "1"
    })
])
    .then(txResult => console.log(txResult))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is precisely what I was looking for; I reworked the Go version and arrived at a very similar approach.